# If count >= row then insert row (substitute for variables and else/if)

Tags: mysql, trigger, count

I do 99% php/javascript work so getting my head around SQL is always a struggle, sorry if I seem dense.

So I've got a table that looks something like this:

```
post_id   |  meta_key    | meta_value
--------------------------------------
1         | requirement  | 3
2         | requirement  | 1
3         | requirement  | 1
1         | adder_id     | 3
1         | adder_id     | 2
1         | adder_id     | 69
2         | adder_id     | 42
2         | complete_date| 20190309040445
```

On an insert trigger I want to run a query that will for each post_id that dose not have a "complete date":

```
INSERT INTO this_table ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
VALUES
( var_post_id, 'complete_date',NOW());
```

But only if

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM this_table
WHERE post_id = var_post_id 
AND meta_key = 'adder_id'
```

is >=

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM this_table
WHERE post_id = var_post_id
AND meta_key = 'requirement'
```

So post_id two is the intended effect (requires 1, has 1, got a complete date) while post_id one is an example of something that should trigger an update (requires 3, has 3, waiting on a complete date) and post_id three should be ignored (requires 1, has 0, just ignore).

Now this would be easy enough with an if/else and 2 or three variables but is this even possible with a mySQL statement? Is there an easier way of going about it within mySQL or should I try and find a PHP solution instead?

Thanks for any assistance, I don't usually ask for help here unless I'm properly stumped and this one really has me going.

Comment: Where does `var_post_id` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with getting all the required counts:

```
SELECT
  post_id,
  meta_value AS required_count
FROM
  this_table
WHERE
  meta_key = 'requirement'
```

Then derive another row set, which is the *actual* counts per `post_id`:

```
SELECT
  post_id,
  COUNT(*) AS actual_count
FROM
  this_table
WHERE
  meta_key = 'adder_id'
GROUP BY
  post_id
```

Now join the two sets as derived tables and filter the results on `actual_count >= required_count` to get the `post_id`s fulfilling the requirement:

```
SELECT
  req.post_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      post_id,
      meta_value AS required_count
    FROM
      this_table
    WHERE
      meta_key = 'requirement'
  ) AS req

  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      post_id,
      COUNT(*) AS actual_count
    FROM
      this_table
    WHERE
      meta_key = 'adder_id'
    GROUP BY
      post_id
  ) AS act

  ON req.post_id = act.post_id

WHERE
  act.actual_count >= req.required_count
```

You can simplify the last query by joining the `act` set directly to `this_table` and slightly modifying the `WHERE` condition by referencing `meta_value` instead of `required_count`:

```
SELECT
  req.post_id
FROM
  this_table AS req
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      post_id,
      COUNT(*) AS actual_count
    FROM
      this_table
    WHERE
      meta_key = 'adder_id'
    GROUP BY
      post_id
  ) AS act  ON req.post_id = act.post_id
WHERE
  -- the filter from the first derived table is moved here
  req.meta_key = 'requirement'

  -- the 'req.required_count' reference is no longer valid or needed;
  -- use 'req.meta_value' instead
  AND act.actual_count >= req.meta_value
```

We are almost there. Now you need to filter out the `post_id`s that already have a `completed_date`. This is called an anti-join (a *self*-anti-join in this specific case, as you excluding rows from a table based on a condition involving the same table). There are different methods of implementing an anti-join. Last I checked, the method that worked in MySQL better than other methods was the one involving a left join and an `IS NULL` check. This is how it would be implemented in your case:

```
SELECT
  req.post_id
FROM
  this_table AS req
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      post_id,
      COUNT(*) AS actual_count
    FROM
      this_table
    WHERE
      meta_key = 'adder_id'
    GROUP BY
      post_id
  ) AS act  ON req.post_id = act.post_id

  -- part of anti-join implementation
  LEFT JOIN this_table AS exc ON req.post_id = exc.post_id
                             AND exc.meta_key = 'completed_date'

WHERE
  req.meta_key = 'requirement'
  AND act.actual_count >= req.meta_value

  -- part of anti-join implementation
  AND exc.post_id IS NULL
```

An outer join could be basically described as an *attempt* to join. So by using a `LEFT JOIN` you are *attempting* to join each `req` row (which is all the `requirement` rows) to each `exc` row (all the `completed_date` rows) on `post_id`. The `IS NULL` check in the `WHERE` clause is saying that actually you want the rows where there was *no match*.

Now that you have all the right `post_id` values, it only remains to add `'complete_date', NOW()` to the SELECT list, and you are ready to insert new rows into the table:

```
INSERT INTO
  this_table (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT
  req.post_id, 'complete_date', NOW()
FROM
  this_table AS req
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      post_id,
      COUNT(*) AS actual_count
    FROM
      this_table
    WHERE
      meta_key = 'adder_id'
    GROUP BY
      post_id
  ) AS act  ON req.post_id = act.post_id
  LEFT JOIN this_table AS exc ON req.post_id = exc.post_id
                             AND exc.meta_key = 'completed_date'
WHERE
  req.meta_key = 'requirement'
  AND act.actual_count >= req.meta_value
  AND exc.post_id IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO  this_table
                ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value ) 
    SELECT  ??var_post_id, 'complete_date', NOW())
        FROM  this_table
        WHERE  post_id = var_post_id
          AND  meta_key = 'requirement'
          AND ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  this_table
            WHERE  post_id = var_post_id
              AND  meta_key = 'adder_id' 
              ) >= meta_value
```

Notes:

- It is not complete since I don't know where `var_post_id` comes from.
- A `SELECT` that returns a single value can be parethesized and used almost anywhere a scalar could be.
- The `SELECT` will either return one row (to be `INSERTed`) or no rows (if the `COUNT` test fails).
- Wouldn't it be better to `UPDATE` something?  (I don't know how you are mapping your logic onto WP's messy key-value store.)
- Is `this_table` really `postmeta`?